# (Assembler)Вывести число в MessageBox

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, процедуры

Задан массив из N элементов. Написать процедуру, определяющую длину самой длинной последовательности расположенных подряд нулевых элементов.
Вывожу через MessageBox но так не получается.

Мой код:

```
.686P   
.model flat, stdcall   
.stack 256   
  
.data   
Mb_OK  EQU   0  
TITLE_    DB          "LAB ", 0   
STR_F     DB          "X = %d", 0  
STR_BUF   DB          256 DUP (0)  
HW        DD          ? 

n            DB              10 ;                               
a            DW              0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1;            
nsd          DD ?
EXTERN wsprintfA:NEAR
EXTERN MessageBoxA@16:NEAR  

.code  
start:
 
mov ds, ax
m1:
    mov di, a
    mov cx, [n]
    mov bx, 0
    mov ax, 0
m2:
    cmp a[di], '0'
    jne m4
    inc ax
    cmp ax, bx
    jle m3
    mov bx, ax
m3:
    jmp m5
m4:
    mov ax, 0
m5:
    inc di
    loop m2
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4ch

mov WORD PTR [nsd],ax

push [nsd]
push OFFSET STR_F
push OFFSET STR_BUF
call wsprintfA
add esp,12

push MB_OK
push OFFSET TITLE_
push OFFSET STR_BUF
push HW
call MessageBoxA@16
ret

END START
```

Comment: У вас смесь досовского кода (с прерываниями) и кода для Windows. Это работать не будет.

Comment: @insolor В том и дело что не могу нигде найти документацию как работать именно с Windows кодом

Comment: 1 - выкинуть все вызовы int, 2 - поменять переменные с 16-битных на 32-битные (ax, di, cx и т.д. на eax, edi, ecx и т.д.), и поменять размер массива с dw на dd. Дальше уже пробовать собирать и запускать, если что-то не работает, то уже исправлять.